# Custom Object Creation in Salesforce - Relation with class

Tags: apex

If I create a custom object (let's say cart__c), will Salesforce automatically create a class for this object which will also be called cart__c (API Name).

Answer (score 1):

The quick (and possibly inaccurate) answer here is a simple "no". The longer answer is "it depends on what you mean by "class", and that level of detail is hidden from us mere mortals (but ultimately it doesn't matter)".

SObjects (`Account`, `Opportunity`, your hypothetical `Cart__c`, etc...) aren't classes per se. That is, you won't find any code for them like you would for a class that you define in Apex.

It'd be more accurate to think of Apex classes and SObjects as *data types*. They can contain data and methods, and can be used in other classes.

Creating a custom object doesn't automatically create an Apex class, but you can still use it in code (Apex, DML, Queries, etc...) immediately after creating it, without any other steps involved.

Comment: Thanks Derek. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You should be looking at creating Domain layer classes, which in your example would be called `Carts.cls`

The resource on domain classes can be found in [Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_patterns_dsl/apex_patterns_dsl_learn_dl_principles) and is part of enterprise patterns:

- Domain
- Selector
- Service
- UnitOfWork